# If we prove that NP = EXP, does that automatically prove that P != NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

If P = DTIME(n^c) and EXP = DTIME(2^n), and we prove that NP = EXP, then it means that NP = DTIME(2^n).
According to the time hierarchy theorem, the set of languages decided in O(f(n)) is bigger than those decided in o(f(n)). So does that not imply P != NP?

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra Not quite: what you describe is [$\mathsf{E}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(complexity)). A correct definition would be $\mathsf{EXP} = \bigcup\limits_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{n^k})$.

Comment: Side note: $\mathsf{EXP}$ is not $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^n)$ but $\mathsf{DTIME}(2^{\text{poly}(n)})$.

Comment: @Nathaniel Yeah, I realized it 10 seconds after posting, deleted that wrong comment…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

It is currently considered unlikely that NP = EXP.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. We know that $\mathsf{P}\subseteq\mathsf{NP}\subseteq \mathsf{EXP}$. However, by diagonalization we know that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{EXP}$, hence one of the inclusions must be strict. So it follows that showing $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{EXP}$, implies $\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{NP}$.